# Como fazer que apenas uma parte do Label fique em negrito?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

Como colocar uma parte da `string` de um `Label` no Windows Forms em negrito via código no C#.

Alguém conhece algo via código para isso?

Comment: Não sei, mas vale a pena tentar <b></b> e [b][/b]

Comment: @fotanus não funcionou nenhum desses 2. Obg pela tentativa. :)

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha No swing, do Java é possível usar tags html. <html>Esse seria um texto <b>parcialmente</b> em negrito em uma JLabel.</html>

Comment: Acho essa funcionalidade essencial no c# para poder ter mais opções de formatação do texto. =\ que pena. Obg

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha o problema não é a linguagem, mas sim a biblioteca gráfica em uso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem algumas soluções que até funcionam, e tem algumas respostas que não solucionam, pelo menos como o AP deseja. Parece que as pessoas esquecem o objetivo de usar OOP. E porque em GUI ela é importante.

É muito simples resolver isto. A classe `Label` permite herança, e é assim que se resolve. Você a herda para outra classe e cria seu próprio *label* com a capacidade de fazer o que deseja, no momento que ela vai renderizar ([`OnPaint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.onpaint?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) - [original](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

Por sorte alguém já desenvolveu uma classe assim e [postou no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2063380/221800), adaptando um pouco (alguns campos são do objeto):

```
class BoldLabel : Label {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        Point drawPoint = new(0, 0);
        string[] array = Text.Split(new char[] { '|' });
        if (array.Length == 2) {
            Font normalFont = this.Font;
            Font boldFont = new(normalFont, FontStyle.Bold);
            Size boldSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(array[0], boldFont);
            Size normalSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(array[1], normalFont);
            Rectangle boldRect = new(drawPoint, boldSize);
            Rectangle normalRect = new(boldRect.Right, boldRect.Top, normalSize.Width, normalSize.Height);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, array[0], boldFont, boldRect, ForeColor);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, array[1], normalFont, normalRect, ForeColor);
        } else {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, drawPoint, ForeColor);                
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/LabalBold.cs).

Aí pode mudar algo para atender a necessidade específica, certamente este código é bem simplificado, mas cria o desejado em seu básico.

Answer (score 3):

Não vai conseguir.

Você pode utilizar o controle RichText que reconhece formatação parcial no texto.

Comment: Será que o Label não oferece esse tipo de suporte? estilo o código '/r' para quebrar a linha. Obg.

Comment: Realmente a princípio não teria como mudar uma parte do texto e no RichText eu já sabia que tinha como. Mas ele não serviria para o que pretendo fazer. Obg @raul-almeida

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível fazer isso com um único controle do tipo `Label`, uma vez que tudo o que ele faz é renderizar uma única `string` sem informação de formatação. Você precisa de dois ou mais controles para montar seu texto visualmente, se for utilizar `Labels`.

Não recomendo isso, pois a formatação pode se tornar cada vez mais complexa caso você precise manter o texto conciso quando o formulário for redimensionado, ou caso o usuário tenha configurado o Windows para utilizar um tamanho de fonte diferente do padrão.

Para conseguir o que você quer sem apelar para diversos controles `Label`, você pode:

- Criar o seu próprio controle que cuide da renderização do texto;
- Utilizar uma imagem `GIF` ou `PNG` com fundo transparente ao invés de uma `Label` (talvez seja a alternativa mais fácil);
- Utilizar outra forma de interface, como `WPF`.

Comment: Irei tentar isso! obg Renan ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternativa A:** Funciona bem.

João, **José** e Maria

```
lblTitulo.Text = 'João, <b>José</b> e Maria';
```

---

**Alternativa B:**

Não é o ideal, porém você pode fazer usando vários labels e isso lhe daria o controle de alterar pelo *code behind* o valor exatamente da região em negrito:

**João**, José e Maria

```
// Se o negrito estiver no início, deverá existir duas labels
// uma do lado da outra, a primeira seria lblTituloNegrito e a outra lblTituloNormal
lblTituloNegrito.Font = New Font(SeuLabel.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
lblTituloNegrito.Text = 'João';
lblTituloNormal.Text = ', José e Maria';
```

João, José e **Maria**

```
// Se o negrito estiver no fim, deverá existir duas labels
// uma do lado da outra, a primeira seria lblTituloNormal e a outra lblTituloNegrito 
lblTituloNormal.Text = 'João, José e ';
lblTituloNegrito.Font = New Font(SeuLabel.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
lblTituloNegrito.Text = 'Maria';
```

João, **José** e Maria.

```
// Se o negrito estiver no meio, deverá existir três labels
// uma do lado da outra, a primeira seria lblTituloNormalInicio,
// a segunda lblTituloNegrito e a terceira lblTituloNormalFim
lblTituloNormalInicio.Text = 'João, ';
lblTituloNegrito.Font = New Font(SeuLabel.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
lblTituloNegrito.Text = 'José';
lblTituloNormalFim.Text = 'e Maria';
```

---

Existem outras alternativas. A **alternativa A** sempre me atendeu. Já teve um caso em específico que achei melhor usar a **alternativa B** mas foi literalmente um problema pontual.

Comment: Seria fazer ao bem meia boca hehe. Mas vlw pela sugestão ! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
SeuLabel.Font = New Font(SeuLabel.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
```

Comment: Eu gostaria de colocar uma parte em negrito, não o texto todo. Obg pela tentativa.

Answer (score -1):

Existe o projeto open source [**HTML Renderer**](https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer) que permite isto que você está pedindo.

Ele possui o controle `HtmlLabel` que possibilita o uso de tags (Ex: `texto em <b>negrito</b>`) conforme já sugerido em comentários na sua pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Coloque um DIV, adicionando os atributos 'runat' e 'id'

```
<div id="textoDIV" runat="server"></div>
```

No code behind chame o div e adicione seu texto pela propriedade 'innerhtml'

```
textoDIV.InnerHtml = "<a href='http://pt.stackoverflow.com/'>Stackoverflow em <strong>português!</strong></a>";
```

Pronto!